# Отправить изображение на сервер, вернуть его обратно, и отобразить в браузере, без создания файла

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

В рамках самостоятельного обучения JS и NodeJs, появился такой вопрос:
Можно ли отправить на сервер изображение(AJAX, POST), вернуть его обратно и отобразить в браузере, без создания файла с изображением на серверной стороне?
По сути, изображение возвращается в том виде, в котором оно пересылалось на сервер - виде строки, в кодировке "base64". 
П.С.: отобразить изображение сразу, после чтения его браузером, с помощью FileReader() я могу.

Comment: Да, такое возможно. Отправляете с клиента строку `base64`, получаете на сервере строку `base64`, отправляете строку `base64` на клиент, получаете на клиенте строку `base64`. Показываете изображение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! С первой частью у меня проблем нет. А вот со второй частью "Показываете изображение.." - проблемы. Расскажите как это сделать?)

Comment: `<img src='base64'>`. А в чем именно проблема? Покажи код, который у вас есть на данный момент.

Comment: @Дмытрык  по поводу конвертации из base64 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, Проблема в отсутствии знаний). Я не знал, что атрибут src принимает что-то другое, кроме URL). Вот проверил учебники, по которым учил HTML, там об этом ни слова)

Comment: @Vadim Bugaiov, спасибо, Ваш ответ помог мне. Отобразить изображение получилось. 
П.С.: почему-то нет галочки для того, чтобы отметить Ваш ответ.

Comment: Потому что это комментарии к вопросу, а не ответы.